# Javascript cookie variable problems

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the cookie on a page after a simple form is submitted.  Here is the code:

```
<script>


function setnewCookie(){

var frack = $('.value').text();
var exp = new Date();                                   // make new date object
exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)); // set it 30 days ahead

setCookie("phoneC", frack, exp);     //save the cookie 
}


</script>
```

The *var frack = $('.value').text();* seems to be where the issue is.  The *.value* is a class in a span tag with a simple phone number.  I want to pass that phone number into the cookie.   Can anyone tell me why this isnt working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this jQuery library](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and it might save you time and frustration. ***Very easy to use***